# Set an app to Full Screen mode, but keep windowed?

Tags: macos, window-manager, fullscreen

When an app is put into full screen mode you typically get rid of the navigation/menu bars, making more space available.  But you lose the option to view other apps at the same time.  Is there any way to set "virtual" screens inside the perimiter of your screen, so you can set these apps to fullscreen mode without them taking up the whole screen?

Comment: Please tag `osx-lion` if you refer to that. It's too early to assume it for the `osx` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Megazoomer](http://ianhenderson.org/megazoomer.html) instead.